# Прокомментируйте код построчно

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте, прошу помочь разобраться и понять следующий пример. Я нуждаюсь в объяснении данного кода, желательно прокомментировать построчно...

```
$(function(){
 $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $that = $(this),
    fData = $that.serialize();
    ....
    // fData = $that.serializeArray();
$.ajax({
  url: $that.attr('action'),
  type: $that.attr('method'),
  data: {form_data: fData},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json){
    if(json){
      $that.replaceWith(json);
    }
  }
   });
 });
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function(){ // Короткая запись $(document).on('ready'.. данная функция выполняется
//когда страница/документ готов к работе

  //на элемент с id="my_form" вешаем событие submit
  $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
    //Отключаем действие по умолчанию, без этой строчки форма будет отправляться без ajax
    e.preventDefault();
    //Присвоение переменной $that. Про this лучше прочитать получше, очень грубо
    //говоря все что есть у элемента, передастся в эту переменную this
    var $that = $(this);
    //fData будет равен строке в формате serialize ГЫ
    fData = $that.serialize();
    //В этой строчке fData будет равна массиву всех аргументов формы
    // fData = $that.serializeArray();
    //Готовим ajax запрос
    $.ajax({
      //У формы есть атрибут action, берем его и подставляем в адрес куда будет послан запрос
      url: $that.attr('action'),
      //У формы есть атрибут method в основном это POST,GET подставляем его
      type: $that.attr('method'),
      //Передаем данные из формы в формате serilize
      data: {form_data: fData},
      //Указываем что формат будет json
      dataType: 'json',
      //При успешном ответе принимаем значение json
      success: function(json){
        //Если данные есть, то...
        if(json){
          //пытаемся заменить $that тем что получили
          $that.replaceWith(json);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: нет комментария для строки с `....`

Comment: //IT IS MAGIC , такой бы подошел?

Comment: А это разве магия? :)

Comment: Бывают такие коды, где вроде все ок, но автор указывает еще ... А что там никто не знает, но почему тогда ставят эти ... гриф секретно? Я склоняюсь к тому что там магия

Comment: _//Меняем данные_? точно?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/ скорее да, чем нет

Comment: и что написано по ссылке? Там где-то есть про изменение данных?

Comment: Да. там есть это. Почему вы так предвзяты ко мне? Если я ошибся, подскажите, пока я ошибку явным образом не вижу

Comment: _Да. там есть это_ - покажи место, пожалуйста. _Почему вы так предвзяты ко мне?_ - потому что код неверен, и объяснения не очень, а хорошее объяснение может занять довольно много места.

Comment: Код неверен или комментарий?

Comment: Я не могу знать что приходит с ajax запроса, если там корректные данные возвращаются, то функция эта произведет замену/поменяет данные/значение/Верстку .. не знаю что возвращается

Comment: Может быть вы имеете ввиду что под Меняем данные подразумевается то, что тут мы их не меняем, а меняем скорее всего верстку?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48705/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: ответ как то что это магическая магия подойдет отлично ) это моя ошибка что написал троеточие вместо "//какие-то дествия в коде"